# how to install ubuntu-14.04.1 32-bit

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, windows-7

I'm the new to Ubuntu. Recently, I downloaded the ISO image (32-bit). I have a laptop in which Windows 7 is pre-installed and now I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7. I have burned a DVD for it but I don't know how to install it.

Comment: You need to boot off of the DVD, keep in mind there are a TON of good articles on installing ubuntu, and this question gets asked a lot. Be sure to look around google and AskUbuntu before asking duplicate questions :)

Comment: See also **[these DVD burning instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)** (of all these resources, that might be what helps you most, I think). Or, for Nero, [this forum topic](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=111589) or [this blog post](http://dwmallisk.blogspot.com/2010/01/how-to-burn-iso-disk-image-through-nero.html).

Answer (score 0):

Boot from the DVD and elect to install right away or "try Ubuntu" which gives you a live session that you can also launch the installer from.

During the install, Ubuntu will detect your Windows installation and ask you what you'd like to do about it, with a popular option being to install Ubuntu alongside Windows by having Ubuntu resize your Windows partition to make space for Ubuntu to install to.

Comment: i tyring this but its not working.actually i dowload the ubuntu 14.04 iso image file,burn to dvd by using nero burner.But this is not work as a bootable dvd.

Comment: Make sure you are not burning the ISO file itself to the disc. Use Nero's "write ISO image to disc" function.